# How to stop thread until user responds

Tags: android, multithreading

I am fairly new to android and I was wondering how I can get a thread in Android to stop untill it gets a responce from the user. I tried the folllowing case:

Count untill 2000

Once it hits 1000 Dialog should open

counter "should" stop untill user presses OK in dialog box.

after the user presses OK the counter should continue from 1000 untill it reaches 2000.

What is actually happening in my code below is that the counter starts once hitting 1000 the dialog opens but the counter continues untill 2000 and doesnt stop and wait at 1000.

Why is this happening? Any ideas? Examples?

CODE:

```
public void onClick(View arg0)
{
     final Runnable r =  

              new Runnable()
              {

                     public void run()
                     {
                        for (int i = 0 ; i < 2000 ; i++)
                        {
                            System.out.println(i);
                            if(i == 1000)
                            {

                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(TmptestActivity.this);
                                final EditText input = new EditText(TmptestActivity.this);
                                alert.setView(input);
                                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                                {
                                     String $input = input.getText().toString();
                                     System.out.println($input);
                                     notify();

                                }});

                                alert.show();
                            }
```

Comment: What do you mean? I am fairly new to this site

Comment: He means that you shall accept answers this giving points to people

Comment: There is a "tick" mark below the down vote on the left side of each answer. choose the best answer and tick that mark. So this way you help others too

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because your alert dialog runs in UI thread, thus your new thread continues to update counter because your alert is in another thread. You should try to use locks (but I'm not very familiar with them). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392139/thread-synchronization-java) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

onClick() is executed on UI thread, and it is bad idea to block it (do not do this at home!). If you like to have your UI dialog topopß up ater some delay,  you shall do:

- spawn another thread
- use sleep() to wait ( not counting in loop )
- pop up your dialog using runOnUiThread()

( alternatively you can use async task: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html )

And for starting and stopping thread  you can use wait() / notify()   on some shared object

Comment: Thanks Konstantin! How can I use the async task for this? I need the UI thread to wait untill the async task will complete? I tried having the thred wait() but it just hangs on the wait....