# Reading a file while it is being written

Tags: android, multithreading, android-file

### Overview

- **Thread 1** Tries to write some data to a file continuously
- **Thread 2** Tries to read from the same file continuously to parse and process data (Read only)

### Problem:

- In thread 2, **the file size remains constant** (this does not refresh as Thread 1 tries to write data to the file) and therefore, I am not able to parse beyond the initial file size.

### Things tried

- **FileInputStream:** Tried to read from an input stream, the file size stays at a constant value (122924 bytes) and never increases
- **RandomAccessFile:** Same result as above, the file size stays constant (122924 bytes), tried r/rw modes
- **FileChannel:** Tried working on a Channel from a FileInputStream, same result as above

Comment: Question is why you need a file between those 2 Threads? why not some simple byte buffer? If those threads are in different proccesses then why don't you use some bridge between them (Service)

Comment: This is because on some devices, Thread 1 produces much more data then Thread 2 can consume in a reasonable, predictable manner. Would like to prevent buffer management and overflow problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock when you write or read your file. This way only one thread can access the file.

Here is the official android website explaining a lock:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Here is an example using a lock:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3392615/2767703

You can also use synchronized to lock an object, here is it explained:

[Java Synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321747/java-synchronization)